# How to count the amount of sub lists in a nested list?

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have created a list:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

How do I get the count of number of sub-lists in `a`?
In this case it is 3.

Answer (score 6):

As with any other list:

```
>>> len(a)
3
```

pythonic way to count sub-lists in a heterogeneous list would be:

```
>>> sum(isinstance(i, list) for i in a)
3
```

Answer (score 5):

I found this page in an effort to learn how to get the sum all all the sublists.  I figured out this could be done using:

```
sum(len(x) for x in a)
```

Maybe that would help someone else...

Comment: This could be helpful, but it doesn't answer his question.

Comment: This gives the total amount of items in sub-lists, and will fail if there is a non-list in `a`. Anyhow, it doesn't answer the question...

Answer (score 4):

This assumes that there could be things other than lists in `a`:

```
sum(1 for x in a if isinstance(x, list))
```

Comment: Don't you need [brackets] for list-creation syntax?  ie. sum([1 for x in a if isinstance(x, list)])

Comment: I'm using a generator expression, not a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

If different types are stored in a list you can count sublists this way:

```
n = 0
for b in a:
    if type(b) == list:
        n += 1
```

Answer (score -1):

1) len(a) is 3.

Answer (score -1):

The number of sub-lists is

```
len(a)
```

Each sublist is an element in the list, so you've got three elements in a, each of them is a list with three elements (which are numbers)

Answer (score -1):

Just to give another aspect of this problem,

```
len(a[0][:])
```

so for example lets say your list is this,

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[7,8,111]]
```

so there are 4 elements in list a, and each list inside of list a has 3 elements therefore,

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[7,8,111]]
print(len(a[0][:]))
```

will give us 3 and this is different than `len(a)`

I believe you can do this to see the sub-string, this is the method that I use for MATLAB and it works fine for python as well.

Comment: But this is not the question.  The question asks exactly for `len(a)` - the amount of sub-lists, not the amount of elements in the sub-lists...